# C++ compression method for txt file

Tags: c++, algorithm, compression, counter

I need to create a function that counts chars in a string in C++, for example, when reading in from a text file that contains:
"aaabbbbbggssj"
the output should be:
"3a5b2g1j"

Im really not sure how to go about it and any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

My code is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#include "Character.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main(){
  int c;
  void count(char [], int []);
//opening text file
  string line = " ";
  fstream my_stream;
  my_stream.open("information.txt");
//loop to cout occurences of each character
  while (getline (my_stream,line))
  {
    cout << line << '\n';
    c += line.length();
    cout << c;

    int numOfChars = line.length();

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++){

  }
  my_stream.close();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is RLE then, have you looked at wikipedia and implemented the algorithm there? https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding

Comment: A simple way would be to create a map to count occurrences for each character. Loop over the string, for each character add +1 to the character entry in the map. In the end just iterate over the map. Makes sense ?

Comment: Also mention: "1j" will add data to your compressed file even if you take a `short` or better a `uint8_t`. And also "2b" will propably not safe any storage unless you safe the number in a custom bit type which would propably involde an identifier for the aligbment which would also not be that saving.

Comment: (Why is the output not to mention `2s`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just count repeating symbols and produce result:

```
string compress(string const& str) {
    string result = "";
    int i = 0;
    while (str[i]) {
        int c = 1;
        while (str[i] == str[i + c]) ++c;
        result += std::to_string(c) + str[i];
        i += c;
    }
    return result;
}
```